Present participle and past participle
I want to understand that  to identify the situations by using present participle and past participle.
1.We have to save increased income for health.
2.We have to save increasing income for health.
#1 I mean, I get increased income  gradually that is permanent.
#2 I mean, I am getting increased money around now that is temporary.
Could I identify those two sentences?

I know what you are trying to say, but sentences 1 and 2 are grammatically incorrect. This is because you are saying "increased income money" like it is the name of something, but it is not. Also, "income money" is redundant because in this context, income means money. It's like you're saying "increased money money".
Here are your fixed sentences:

We have to save our increased income for our health.

We have to save our increasing income for our health.


#1 Means that your income was lower before, and then it increased. So now, you say it is increased income.
A similar example would be if your car broke and then it got fixed. You would say "This is my fixed car!"
#2 Means that your income is increasing continually--it is increasing right now while you talk. So that is why you say "our increasing income".
A similar example would be if you're talking about a tree you planted. You would say "My tree is growing!"

Yes, so I will specify that all participles are not related to the meanings of both temporary and permanent.They just show action and I can use them without expression of permanent and temporary.I mean that I don't need to think about permanent and temporary.Both meanings permanent and temporary are also unnecessary when using participle.@Xighteous

Yes, participles don't necessarily refer to something being temporary and permanent. They can also indicate to whether something is an ongoing process, or a completed process. The above 1 and 2 are examples of this.

Thank you so much sir@Xighteous

You're welcome! Glad to help anytime.
